# Wordpress Theme Copyright Editing (Footer)

Tags: wordpress, themes, copyright-display

How do i edit WordPress Di Business theme footer copyright?
I am trying to no success, especially in the Cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this via c panel then just go to this path:

wp-content -> themes -> Select Your theme -> Select Footer.php

Then find the `<div id="footer">` ,remove all dynamic code and write your html contents.

dont worry,You can do even if you are not so handy in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below step:
Go to the admin panel.

```
Appearance -> customize -> Di Business Options -> Footer Copyright Options -> and edit Footer Center
```

like: Edit with custom Terms of Use - Privacy Policy

Look at the screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECpHM.png